# Mule ESB Anypointstudio not able to copy project zip file to the embedded Mule instance

Tags: mule-studio

Anypoint studio Version: 7.1.2.
getting below error for a simple project. can u tell me how to fix this.

Unable to copy project zip file to the embedded Mule instance. Project: [Mule Project] Name: training-american-ws - Domain: default
Destination 'C:\Program Files\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.1.ee_7.1.2.201803261303\mule\apps-staging\training-american-ws.jar' directory cannot be created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>training-american-ws</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule-application</packaging>

<name>training-american-ws</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <app.runtime>4.1.1</app.runtime>
    <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.1.1</mule.maven.plugin.version>
<munit.version>2.1.1</munit.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <goal>coverage-report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <coverage>
                    <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                    </formats>
                </coverage>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
        <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
        <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue in Mac OS, Try moving AnypointStudio to Applications and Run the project again. It worked for me.

Happy Learning!

Regards,
Sivaji

Answer (score 0):

do you have write permissions in the Studio installation directory?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have dependency for the domain project in pom.xml. If the issue will still remains please, restart Anyponit Studio as administrator.